# How to implement a function that also has a prototype of something else

Tags: javascript, function

I have a FunctionArray object which I want to use to call several functions at once. Basically what you see here is what I have so far, but one thing that would be nice is to just call a function array like `myFunctionArrayInstance()`. Is there a way to do that or is it just not possible?

```
var FunctionArray =  function(){
    this.apply = function(){
        var args = arguments;
        this.forEach(function(e,i){
            e.apply(args);
        });
    }
    this.call = function(){
        var args = arguments;
        this.forEach(function(e,i){
            e.call(args);
        });
    }
    this.bind = function(){
        var args = arguments;
        var binds = [];
        this.forEach(function(e,i){
            binds.push(e.bind(args));
        });
        return function(){
            var args2 = arguments;
            binds.forEach(function(e,i){
                e.apply(args2);
            });
        };
    };

};
FunctionArray.prototype = [];
```

And I use it like this.

```
var initers = new FunctionArray();
initers.push(function(){/*something here*/});
initers.push(function(){/*something here*/});
initers();
```

Comment: can you provide sample how you want use it and sample input output?

Comment: @Grundy, ok, I added an example.

Comment: are you sure that need exactly create object like function instead simple use function?

Comment: Well, I want to combine function and array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a cool construct :) Alas, if the constructed objects are descendants of array, it won't be callable. On the other hand, why not make it a function constructor (which would make the instances callable), and augment this instance with array-like mechanisms for storing and retrieving the functions within?

I'm thinking:

```
(function(){ 'use strict';
function makeFunctionArray(){
    var functionArray = function(){
        functionArray.functions.forEach(function(f){
            f();
        });
    }

    functionArray.functions = [];
    functionArray.push=function(fnToAdd){
        functionArray.functions.push(fnToAdd);
    }
    functionArray.pop=function(){
        return functionArray.functions.pop();
    }
    //and so on... you can add any array functionality you need
    //(maybe even bracket notation with some fiddling?)

    return functionArray;
}

//using it:
var fa = makeFunctionArray();
typeof fa; //'function'
fa.push(function(){console.log(123);});
fa.push(function(){console.log(456);});
fa(); //-> outputs '123' then '456'
})();
```

Edit: cleaned up code according to Grundy's suggestions.

Comment: `var self = this;

self = function(){` here you reassign `self`, so after it not refers to `this`

Comment: you're right, that line is superfluous. (I paste my code too hastily, it had some unneeded lines and debug logging)

Comment: if you remove `var self = this;` nothing changes

Comment: @Grundy, If I remove that line, self becomes globally available :-p But that line's not really the point of the whole thing. (The whole self/this shenanigans was just lazyness on my part to avoid dealing with this changing, I didn't see it was not going to be necessary when I started typing up this answer - I'll edit the code a bit.)

Comment: but i mean that you not use `this`

Comment: and before editing also :-) you reassign self at once, so not use `this` everywere :-)

Comment: also not needed _new_

Comment: @Grundy Thanks, I changed that too and attributed you for the cleanup. This code *(meant more as a fiddle anyway)* didn't take the direction I originally thought it would, and it shows in all these things. I won't make any substantial edits to the solution, because it has been accepted as an answer, but I might append an other approach later.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure looked interesting, but sadly if you want a *Function* (as opposed to a constructed *Object*) to have a custom prototype chain you need to use the very costly `Object.setPrototypeOf` and I would not be surprised if it produced lots of unexpected results. You'll need to add a method which does the invocation.

I think it would be easier to keep control over everything if you don't put your *Array* in the prototype and instead have a property on the instance which holds your *Functions* and copy wrapped versions of the methods over from *Array* that you need. I also added an *invoke* and re-implemented *length*.

Then basically everything is in the prototype *except* the *Array* of your functions. After the initial definition creating instances should require very little time/memory.

```
function FunctionArray() {
    this.fns = [];
}
FunctionArray.prototype = Object.create(null);
(function () {
    var i, arr = ['push', 'pop', 'shift', 'unshift', 'splice'];

    function addToProto(key, fn) {
        FunctionArray.prototype[key] = function () {
            return fn.apply(this.fns, arguments);
        };
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        addToProto(arr[i], Array.prototype[arr[i]]);
    }

    Object.defineProperty(
        FunctionArray.prototype,
        'length',
        {
            get: function () {return this.fns.length;},
            set: function (x) {return this.fns.length = x;}
        }
    );

    FunctionArray.prototype.item = function (i) {
        return this.fns[i];
    };

    FunctionArray.prototype.invoke = function () {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.fns.length; ++i) {
            this.fns[i].apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };

    FunctionArray.prototype.call = function (ctx) {
        var i, args = arguments.slice(1);
        for (i = 0; i < this.fns.length; ++i) {
            this.fns[i].apply(ctx, args);
        }
    };

    FunctionArray.prototype.apply = function (ctx, args) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.fns.length; ++i) {
            this.fns[i].apply(ctx, args);
        }
    };

    FunctionArray.prototype.bind = function () {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.fns.length; ++i) {
            this.fns[i] = Function.prototype.bind.apply(this.fns[i], arguments);
        }
    };
}());
```

Now you can do something like

```
var fa = new FunctionArray();
fa.push(function (fizz) {console.log(this, fizz)});
fa.push(function (buzz) {console.log(this, buzz)});
fa.bind({'foo': 'bar'});
fa.length; // 2
fa.invoke('baz'); // logs {foo: "bar"} "baz" twice
```

---

### However,

It is possible but strongly not reccomended, using [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

```
function FunctionArray() {
    var foo = function () {
        return foo.invoke.apply(foo, arguments);
    };
    Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, FunctionArray.prototype);
    foo.fns = [];
    return foo;
}
FunctionArray.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
// continue from here as above
```

Now

```
var fa = new FunctionArray();
fa.push(function (fizz) {console.log(this, fizz)});
fa.push(function (buzz) {console.log(this, buzz)});
fa.bind({'foo': 'bar'});
fa.length; // 2
fa('baz'); // logs {foo: "bar"} "baz" twice
```

Comment: Just curious, what is invoke?

Comment: OP ideally wanted `fa('baz')` instead using `invoke` :-)

Comment: @Grundy you lose all of the benifits of the prototype if you do that though :(

Comment: @PaulS., but what if we add it to prototype for our function?

Comment: @Grundy all _functions_ inherit from `Function.prototype`. The only way to make one which doesn't would be to use `Object.setPrototypeOf` which isn't a good idea as it's both unexpected by the interpreter and especially unexpected for functions, `Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, Object.create(Function.prototype));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82851/discussion-between-grundy-and-paul-s).